# Ayuda con estructura de base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

tengo un sistema para envio de archivos y llevo el control en dos tablas, una para guardar nombre de archivos y estatus de envio y procesamiento, y otra en el que guardo los detalles como mensajes de error al enviar o exito al procesar.

Ahora tengo la necesidad de enviar el mismos archivo a dos destinos diferentes y necesito llevar el control de los archivos que se envian al segundo destino

Como primera medida se me ocurrio agregar otras colunmas a las tablas que ya tengo para agregar los estatus de envio para el segundo destino, pero analizando llevar un control para saber a cual destino si se envio y a cual no seria mal revoltoso al ver la tabla directamente

Otra opcion es crear otras dos tablas y usarlas para llevar el control exclusivo  para ese destino

Cual creen que se la mejor u que otra opción me recomendarian?

Answer (score 2):

La mejor opción seria hacer una tabla (BD) donde relaciones el mensaje con el destino, ya que por como dices un mensaje puede ser enviado a varias destino, entonces la tabla tendría el **id** del mensaje y el **id** del destino:

Tabla relacional entre el mensaje y el destino:

```
---------------------------
|     destino_mensaje     |
---------------------------
| id_mensaje | id_destino |
---------------------------
| 1          | 1          |
---------------------------
| 1          | 2          |
---------------------------
| 1          | 4          |
---------------------------
| 2          | 1          |
---------------------------
```

Con esto puedes agregar varios destinos a un solo mensaje

Comment: hasta donde se lee en la pregunta, el OP requiere ayuda en las tablas de la base de datos, no en las tablas a nivel de HTML; creo entendiste mal la pregunta

Comment: ya lo arregle lo que pasa es que no sabia como colocarlo con el markdown, si lees bien el enunciado estaba hablando del BD @AlfredoPaz

Answer (score 0):

Edit: @David no aterrice muy bien tu idea, esta es la estructura de las tablas que tengo actualmente:

```
-----------------            ----------------
|   fileshead   |            |   filesdet   |
-----------------            ----------------
| id            |            | id           |
-----------------            ----------------
| periodo       |            | idhead       |
-----------------            ----------------
| archivo       |            | errid        |
-----------------            ----------------
| status_envio  |            | description  |
-----------------            ----------------
| retry_envio   |            | tiporeg      |
-----------------            ----------------
| status_proces |           
-----------------           
| retry_proces  |           
-----------------
```

en fileshead se guardan datos del archivo como periodo y nombre y los estatus del envio, y en filesdet se guardan los detalles al realizar el envio o procesar el archivo ahora para manejar un segundo destino es en donde estoy viendo como hacerle, con tu idea se me ocurre agregar un campo que en fileshead que se llame destino y hacer una doble insercion del registro con la diferencia de que el campo de destino dara la pauta para poder controlar a donde mandar cada archivo, y filesdet quedaria igual llevando el registro del archivo, pero siento que eso seria duplicar la informacion en la tabla de fileshead

Comment: Esto es una respuesta?